# UK visa start date and Flight Depature Time

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, international-travel

So I’ve got a UK Visa with a start date of the 30th of April and I’ve booked a Flight which departs 23:55 on the 29th of April. That’s 5 minutes before my visa becomes active.

Will this pose a problem for me? I have to absolutely be in Manchester by 1st of May for an important meeting.  The flight is Turkish airlines Abuja to Manchester, so there’s a layover in Istanbul.

Comment: (That question is about Schengen but it doesn't make any difference.)

Answer (score 11):

The British authorities absolutely won't care when you *left home*. They care about when you *arrive in their country*.

The airline's check-in staff *should not* care about things the UK authorities don't care about. In principle they may be badly trained and think it matters whether the visa is valid already when you check in. This is not particularly likely, and there's not anything you can do in advance to guard 100% against such incompetence.

It *might possibly* help if you can say at check in that you phoned the airline's customer service ahead of time and was told that it's OK -- at least in the sense of convincing an incompetent agent to check with their superiors instead of rejecting you out of hand.

But all in all I don't think it is worth worrying unduly about.

Comment: It's a perfectly normal situation that they see every day. There is no reason to worry about it. Documents only need to be valid on arrival, not on departure.